# Compiling and using a C++ static library in an objective C iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, static-libraries

I've tried literally everything on the planet and am about to pull my hair out...

I'm trying to write and build a static library in C++, and then include and call it from an app in Objective C. Simple enough. I get the following linker error when trying to run the app:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"spmEstimatorMobile::spmCalculate(double*, double*, double*)", referenced from:
  -[RecordViewController outputAccelerationData:] in RecordViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried EVERYTHING. The app calling file has the .mm extension, I've made sure the compilers that are set for both the library and the app are the same, I've ensured that I build the library for the same architecture (armv7) that I'm building the app for, I've included the library by adding it in the build phase settings page, I'm compiling all sources when building the library as well, I've tried running lipo etc. to make a universal binary just in case ... I just can't figure this out...

If it helps, this is on XCode 6.2., I'm trying to deploy to my iPhone 5 running iOS 8.1. I've double checked all the deployment targets too.

Any ideas??? Anyone!

EDIT: I'm using STL stuff in the C++ static lib (i.e. vectors, etc.) .. not sure if that makes a difference...

Comment: C++ has name mangling--you probably need to expose a function with extern C linkage for Obj C to call.

Comment: I looked into that too. Apparently using the extern handler is supposed to be an alternative to the .mm renaming convention i.e. either you add the extern, or you rename to .mm. Anyhow, I tried adding extern but I get an error right at the extern "C" point: "Expected member name or ; after declaration specifiers'. I don't have any missing semi-colons or brackets etc..

Comment: Non-static member functions have a different calling convention as well--the this pointer gets passed implicitly.  You probably need a non-member function that's extern c that takes your object by pointer (maybe even a void ptr), then casts to your class type and calls your member.

Comment: The function I'm calling is a static function...